# Presto SQL - Combining Columns

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

I am using AWS Athena to run a query against my data set to combine values from different columns found in various data sets (ex. There is a parquet file for each of client 1-4). However, the output is simply empty for "all_clients_total_clicks". The strange thing is that similar code on another table is working - just not for the one I'm currently working on.

Can someone please help me confirm whether my syntax is acceptable? Or point me in the right direction/documentation for review? SQL Below:

```
SELECT "columnA",
    sum("columnX") AS "TotalImpressions",
    cast(sum("client1_column_total_clicks") AS double)
    + cast(sum("client2_column_total_clicks") AS double)
    + cast(sum("client3_column_total_clicks") AS double)
    + cast(sum("client4_column_total_clickss") AS double) AS "all_clients_total_clicks"
FROM "db_name"."db_table"
Group by "columnA"
```

Comment: can you please provide a [mre]

Comment: What is displayed if you select those `cast(sum(...))` separately (one per column) rather than adding them together?

Answer (score 0):

The issue stems from trying to add null values. Using Try + Coalesce resolved it for me.

[Presto DB Documentation for Conditionals](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#functions-conditional--page-root)